# Add overlay image when the class is added to the div

Tags: html, css

**My Problem**

I want to be able to handle my CSS this way, that when I add a class named "sold-out" to my div , it should **add a sold-out overlay stamp**. At the moment I have the problem, that it seems like I am destroying the CSS of other classes. However I hope you can help me with a good solution.

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="rotate sold-out">
    <a href="images/packages/background01.jpg" rel="imagebox" title="">
    <img src="images/packages/background01.jpg" alt=""/></a>
</div>
```

As you can see I have inserted an image there and the sold-out stamp (which is a transparent .png) should be shown at the highest layer ofcourse.

**My CSS try:**

```
.sold-out {
    content: url(../images/sold_out_stamp.png);
}
```

**This is what happened:**
The image inside the div is completely gone. I only see the Sold-out-stamp with a white background.

Comment: Yes it is a transparent .png as stated : http://puu.sh/eQE2H/5055c89867.jpg

Comment: Here's a nice css-only option: https://codepen.io/sonukry/pen/aNPxXw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. Instead of replacing the sold-out element's content with the overlay image (and thereby replacing it entirely) you should set the pseudo element's content and position it over the sold-out element.

```
.sold-out{ position:relative; }
.sold-out::before{
    content:url(../images/sold_out_stamp.png);
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

*didn't test, but should work in theory... If you make a fiddle with the correct images linked I'm happy to refine, but this should at least be close.

Let me know if you need further direction.

Comment: Yup.  this would be the correct way to do it.  Demo of the process in action: http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/q2mvd4wL/ (test image isn't a png though)

Comment: Unfortunately the z-index isnt working for me. Doesn't matter which value I use for z-index, it is always behind another div's image. For example I have another badge usually, but this badge is always in front of the sold-out-stamp, even tho that it hasn't even the z-index implemented

Comment: z-index only applies to elements in its stacking context. In this case it might not even be needed to place it above the slide-out child elements (I put it in to be safe). But what's probably happening is your badge is in a higher stacking context which means no changes to this z-index will fix it. This might require rethinking your HTML structure. I'd have to see your full code to be sure...

More on stacking contexts https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context